# Slapd execution fails after installation

Tags: openldap

When I run OpenLDAP I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/libexec/slapd: Symbol `ldap_int_global_options' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
```

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.1, after updating from 12.04 with do-release-upgrade -d.

The version of OpenLDAP is 2.4.39.

What could cause that and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The openldap library used by your slapd differs significantly for which it was intended to be used.

Check if some type of library compatibility/configurability problems exists with some apt command (`apt-get update`, `apt-get -f install`, `dpkg --configure -a`).

If there is nothing to be fixed, the best solution were to recompile your openldap, although it means nearly surely that there same type on uncleanness about your distro.

Openldap recompilation is relatively simple:

```
apt-get build-dep openldap
apt-get source openldap
cd <your openldap source root>
debian/rules build
fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

...and reinstall your packages with some `dpkg -i` commands.

Probably you will find some problems around the compilation, these errors you had to put here as new questions.